# PHP | Why array_push() adds a " by each value?

Tags: php, json

I try to write an api that connects to several servers and get a son file.
For each service, i write an extra function that pulls the data and cast it to json format.

also i have an array the functions result will put into.

`myFunc1` return produced:
`{"KEY1":"foo","KEY2":"bar"}`

`myFunc2` return produced:
`{"VAL1":"foo","VAL2":"bar"}`

Than to add the content:

```
$jsondata = array("Func1"=>array(),"Func2"=>array());
$jsondata["Func1"][] = myFunc1();
$jsondata["Func2"][] = myFunc2();
```

If I now do a `json_encode($jsondata);` I will get:

```
{"Func1":["{\"KEY1\":\"foo\",\"KEY2\":\"bar\"}"],"Func2":["{\"VAL1\":\"foo\",\"VAL2\":\"bar\"}"]
```

Thats almost fine but in `{"Func1":["{\"KEY` the `"` between `:[` and `{\"K` is to much.

PHP automatically add this but so my son in invalid and i don't know how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like `myFunc1` and `myFunc2` are returning `json_encode`'d strings, when you should be returning the arrays. You should only `json_encode` the final product, unless you want this to happen.

Comment: *"PHP automatically add this"* -- PHP does not add anything automatically.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're inserting `myFunc1()` into the array as a JSON encoded string. Try returning an array in `myFunc1()` and `myFunc2()`, and then `json_encode()` everything as a whole.

If you are getting the JSON encoded string from another place and just returning it in the function, then `json_decode()`, (with `true` as a parameter, to get it as an array, not an object) like this:

```
$jsondata = array("Func1"=>array(),"Func2"=>array());
$jsondata["Func1"][] = json_decode(myFunc1(), true);
$jsondata["Func2"][] = json_decode(myFunc2(), true);
```

Comment: hi :), this is the point... i have to json_decode first and if the jsondata array is filled, just an json_encode($jsondata) - thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. If your question is resolved, please close your question by accepting the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Your funct should return array  not string  (as  json)

eg:

```
$jsondata["Func1"][] = ['KEY1'=>'foo','KEY2' => 'bar'];
$jsondata["Func2"][] = ['VAL1'=>'foo','VAL2' => 'bar'];

json_encode($jsondata);
```